# 「メールアドレスのfrom」と「送信メールアドレスごとに HELO パケットを対応させる」について

Tags: centos, postfix

**環境**
・CentOS 7
・postfix 2.10.1

**同一サーバでバーチャルドメイン運営**
・a.example.com
・a.example.net

**最終的にやりたいこと**
・a.example.comからメール送信した時のfromをmail.example.comにしたい
・a.example.netからメール送信した時のfromをmail.example.netにしたい

---

**質問**
・[送信メールアドレスごとに HELO パケットを対応させる](https://www.bscre8.com/bslife/2017/08/31/%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3%E3%83%AB%E3%83%89%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E7%92%B0%E5%A2%83%E3%81%AE-postfix-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A6%E3%80%81%E3%83%A1%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%AC/)と書いてあるのですが、HELO パケットの意味が良く分かりません
・この内容を試したらやりたいことができますか？

**補足**
・まだ試していません
・理由は「マッピング用データベースを作成」とか書いてあるので、失敗したときに戻すのが大変そうだと思ったので…

Comment: HELOもEHLOも元はHelloから来ているので間違いではないですが、記事中のパケットの話は`Helloパケット`では？

Comment: あなたの「やりたいこと」は「エンベロープ送信者アドレスのドメイン名が a.example.com の時に配送先 SMTP サーバーに対して EHLO あるいは HELO コマンドで名乗るホスト名を mail.example.com に…」ということですよね? 質問は正確に。「…fromをmail.example.comにしたい」の「from」とは何?? それに「HELO パケット」なんて表現は聞いたことがありません。「SMTP のHELO あるいは EHLO コマンドのこと」だとは思いますが、その筆者の独自の表現であって、一般的ではないですね。

Comment: 「from」は「MAIL FROM コマンド」の意味で書きました。「MAIL FROM コマンド」と「EHLO あるいは HELO コマンド」はそれぞれ異なるコマンドで、何れもその値を自由に設定可能ですか？　そしてチェックが厳しいメールサーバでは何れも「適当に設定すると拒否されることがありますか」？